# Error while running MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner against C# project

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-msbuild-runner, sonarscanner

I’m trying to use MSBuild SonarQube scanner for my C# project. RootFolder has a .sln file, and each project (.csproj) is created in a separate folder inside the root folder. I've the project property file in RootFolder.

SonarQube server (LTS version 6.7.5) is up fine.

My Current env details:

Visual Studio **2010**
.Net Framework **4.5.2**
MSBuild version **4**
sonarScanner for MSBuild **4.3.1.1372**
Sonar Csharp Plugin version : **7.3.2.6129**

When I’m trying to run below ‘begin’ command from project root directory, I see this error:

```
M:\myProjectCsharp>MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:”myProjectCsharp”/n: “myProjectCsharp”/v:”1.0”

Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: '!!0[] System.Array.Empty()'.
   at SonarScanner.MSBuild.Program.Execute(String[] args, Boolean showDeprecatedWarning)
   at MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

I guess it has something to do with compatibility of .Net Framework or MSBuild version ?

Also, what's the role of visual studio here, I already got.sln, .csproject and their corresponding .cs files in respective project directory under RootFolder 'myProjectCsharp'

(I don’t see any error if I simply run the sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.3.1.1372-net46\sonar-scanner-3.2.0.1227\bin\sonar-scanner but this doesn’t seems to update anything on dashboard (Just show 0 Bugs,Vulnerabilities & code smells) )

Any clue please  ?

Thanks.

Comment: VS2010 should be replaced by VS2015+. See [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Compatibility)

Comment: Thanks Jeroen. I'll upgrade and give it a try again.

Comment: You shouldn't need a sonar-project.properties file either. The Scanner for MSBuild will generate one.

Comment: It's ok now after upgrading to MSBuild 14 with VS2015. Looks all good. Thanks Guys.